# Как убрать значение акции в свойстве товара

Tags: php, битрикс, php7

Есть товары в админке битрикса с просроченной акцией. То есть у каждого товара есть свойство `EVENTS`.

По скрину видно что свойство может быть как и одно так и несколько.

[image: Скрин товара с админки]

Я решил сделать так:

1. Выбрать сначала все акции срок которых истек и получить их `ID`. За это отвечает следующий код:

```
    $arOrder      = array();
    $arFilter     = array(
        "IBLOCK_ID"    => 22,
        "!ACTIVE_DATE" => "Y",
    );
    $res          = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(), $arFilter, false);
    $allOutAction = array();
    while ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
        $arFields[] = $ob->GetFields();
        $arrID = array_column($arFields, 'ID');
    };
```

2. Далее я получаю список всех акционных товаров, делаю я это так:

```
    $arFilter2 = array(
        "IBLOCK_ID"        => "2",
        "!PROPERTY_EVENTS" => false,
    );
    $all_res   = CIBlockElement::GetList(
        array(

        ),
        $arFilter2,
        false,
        false,
        array(
            'ID',
            'PROPERTY_EVENTS'
        )
    );
    while ($ob2 = $all_res->GetNextElement()) {
        $arFields2[] = $ob2->GetFields();
    };
    //echo('');
    //print_r($arFields2);
    //echo('');

    foreach ($arFields2 as $prod) {
        $prodEventsId = ($prod["PROPERTY_EVENTS_VALUE"]);
            foreach($prodEventsId as $EventsId) {

                if ($arrID = $EventsId) {
                   $prod["PROPERTY_EVENTS_VALUE"] = array();
                    $prod["~PROPERTY_EVENTS_VALUE"] = array();
                    $prod["PROPERTY_EVENTS_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID"] = array();
                    $prod["~PROPERTY_EVENTS_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID"] = array();

                }

            }
```

при этом я получаю на выходе массив с товарами (для примера приведу один товар) - где  подмассив с акциями - пустой.
Вот сам подмассив:

```
[PROPERTY_EVENTS_VALUE] => Array
        (
        )
```

и соответсвенно полностью вывод товара:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 2956
    [~ID] => 2956
    [PROPERTY_EVENTS_VALUE] => Array
        (
        )

    [~PROPERTY_EVENTS_VALUE] => Array
        (
        )

    [PROPERTY_EVENTS_DESCRIPTION] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [~PROPERTY_EVENTS_DESCRIPTION] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [PROPERTY_EVENTS_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID] => Array
        (
        )

    [~PROPERTY_EVENTS_PROPERTY_VALUE_ID] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Но при это у этого же товара, в админке, свойство акций заполнено. Подскажите что я не так делаю, уже второй день бьюсь.

Вот скрин с админки:

[image: скрин товара с админки после выполнения скрипта]

фасеты перестроил - не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Для поля типа список попробуйте в фильтре указать вот так:

```
$arFilter2 = array(
    "IBLOCK_ID"        => "2",
    "!PROPERTY_EVENTS_VALUE" => false,
);
```

в документации по `GetList` в разделе фильтр об этом говорится